# puppeteer: get JSON response of a specific request as in the network tab of DevTools

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I'd like to directly get the response of the request from twitter shown in the screenshot

The current puppeteer code is shown below. Could anybody show me how to modify it so that it will get the JSON response directly from the browser? Thanks.

```html
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    //  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false
        
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://twitter.com/login');

    await page.waitFor(3000)
    await page.type('input[name="session[username_or_email]"]', 'username');
    await page.waitFor(3000)
    await page.type('.js-password-field', 'password');
    await page.waitFor(3000)
    await page.click('.EdgeButtom--medium');
    await page.waitFor(3000)
    await page.goto('https://mobile.twitter.com/holidaytimeuk/status/1213629088671371267');
    await page.waitFor(3000)

 const linkHandlers = await page.$x("//*[@id='react-root']/div/div/div/main/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/section/div/div/div/div[1]/div/article/div/div[6]/div[2]/a");
    if (linkHandlers.length > 0) {
        const [response] = await Promise.all([
    page.waitForResponse(response => response.url().includes('https://api.twitter.com/2/timeline/liked_by.json')),
    linkHandlers[0].click()
]);
const dataObj = await response.json();
console.log(dataObj);
    } else {
        throw new Error("Link not found");
    }

})();
```

[Here is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tB1ja.jpg)

Comment: You want to use `page.on('response')` I believe

Comment: help me please.

Answer (score 0):

It always takes me a while of fiddling to get things working with Puppeteer, but take a look at [page.evaluate](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.0.0&show=api-pageevaluatepagefunction-args). This lets you run a function in the context of the page.

Comment: i try to add but nothing response, please help me
    const firstRequest = await page.waitForRequest('https://api.twitter.com/2/timeline/');
    const finalRequest = await page.waitForRequest(request => request.url() === 'https://api.twitter.com/2/timeline/' && request.method() === 'GET');
    return firstRequest.url();